# How to issue organize desktop command from the shell

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I usually interact with the shell, but I prefer to have the items on the desktop organized. Is there a command or a scripting interface to organize the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your question is. However, if it is that you want to be able to "organise desktop icons" (i.e. into a grid) from the command-line then this will likely depend on what flavour and version of Ubuntu you are using, because they use different managers.

There is a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121357/organize-desktop-by-name-in-a-script) with no answer. However, there is quite a lot of discussion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330986/how-to-order-desktop-icons-by-name-in-xfce) with some very good answers, including a custom-made perl script that appears to do exactly that.